# Почему при объединении двух списков из бинарных чисел, в итоговом списке числа преобразуются в десятичный формат?

Tags: erlang

Конвертирую десятичное число в двоичный формат:

```
A = integer_to_list(5, 2).
```

И добавляю к полученному списку список из нулей:

```
A ++ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0].
```

Получаю `[49, 48, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.
Нужно при объединении получить `[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что у вас получается список символов "101", а не чисел. Символы имеют числовое представление, согласно таблице ASCII, и символу 0 соответствует код 48, а символу 1, соответственно, 49.

Попробуйте вычесть код цифры 0 из каждого элемента массива, получаемого после вызова функции `integer_to_list(5, 2)`.

Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
A = lists:map(fun(X) -> X-$0 end, integer_to_list(5, 2)).
```

Answer (score 3):

Немного более вменяемый способ:

```
i2bl(I) when is_integer(I) -> 
  i2bl(<<I>>, []).

i2bl(<<>>, Acc) ->
  Acc;
i2bl(<<B:1, Rest/bitstring>>, Acc) -> 
  i2bl(Rest, [B|Acc]).
```

Пример использования:

```
1> i2bl(5).
[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: А клоз с нулем не забыл?

Comment: @DmitryBelyaev А что не так с нулём?

Comment: Это я не заметил, что там переменная B биндится. А код запускать было лень.